I can not run R in Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
I would like an help from an error that I am experiencing after installing R. I followed all steps from "https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/fullREADME.html#installing-r" to install R in Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. However, the following error is reported after starting R in my terminal: "/usr/local/lib/R/bin/exec/R: error while loading shared libraries: libicuuc.so.72: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". Is there anyway to fix it?

I can run R just fine on some Ubuntu 24.04 containers as for example rocker/r2u:noble:
$ docker run --rm -ti rocker/r2u:noble bash
root@ddcecd84f2b5:/# cd
root@ddcecd84f2b5:~# R

R version 4.4.1 (2024-06-14) -- "Race for Your Life"
Copyright (C) 2024 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

> q()
Save workspace image? [y/n/c]: n
root@ddcecd84f2b5:~# 
root@ddcecd84f2b5:~# apt update -qqq
root@ddcecd84f2b5:~# apt-cache policy r-base-core
r-base-core:
  Installed: 4.4.1-1.2404.0
  Candidate: 4.4.1-1.2404.0
  Version table:
 *** 4.4.1-1.2404.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu noble-cran40/ Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4.4.0-2.2404.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu noble-cran40/ Packages
     4.3.3-2build2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe amd64 Packages
root@ddcecd84f2b5:~# 

This is the standard package from the standard R backport at CRAN.  What do you have?

Thank you very much for your response. I think it is very usefull to know others ways. However, I am sorry but I have never tried docker yet. Currently, I could install in my mamba environment, but i would like to install in Ubuntu because I would like to use with Rstudio (because in mamba/conda I can only use latest R base alone and Rstudio is incompatible with latest R when I tried installing in the same enviroment).

Sure but note that most R users, and most R releases (ie at CRAN, RStudio itself, ...) are not for Conda and mixing generally does not work.  Also, what works in an Ubuntu Docker container is an illustration of what will work in a similar 'plain' Ubuntu installation.  Docker makes is easier to test as it offers 'self-contained' executable units.

Thanks, I appreciate the explanation. I think that maybe my Ubuntu have may be corrupted and I will make a fresh reinstall and after this I will reinstall R (recently I made an upgrade to 24.04 LTS and maybe something gone wrong in this process).

I reinstalled Ubuntu 24.04 LTS and after I was able to install R and Rstudio without any issues I think it was my Ubuntu became corrupted from the upgrade (23.10 -> 24.04).

Good to know. Feel free to accept the answer then as it suggested / showed that a 'normal' system woould work just fine.

It looks like the lib is not found, try the following steps:
sudo apt install libicu72

it may also be a path issue, check your path with:
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH

If the path is empty attempt to set it:
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/libicu/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH  # Replace path with actual location
R


libicu72 could not be found in after trying "sudo apt install libicu72". Also, I tried "echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH" and i got no result. Could it be a path configuration problem? How can I find libicu path in my Ubuntu? Sorry, I am new to linux.

I reinstalled Ubuntu 24.04 LTS and after I was able to install R and Rstudio without any issues I think it was my Ubuntu became corrupted from the upgrade (23.10 -> 24.04).
